# Question on quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The following question is taken from the Book "Introduction to Mathematical structures and proofs:

Let $A = \{1, 2, π\}$, and let $P$ be the statement $x \in A$ and $x \in \Bbb Z.$ Determine
the truth value of each of the following implications, and justify
briefly. Take the set $\Bbb R$ of real numbers as the universal set.

(a)$(\exists x)P \rightarrow  (\forall x)P$

(b) $(\forall x)P \rightarrow  (\exists x)P$

Although It seems that I am lead to believe that a  would be false and b true.

Comment: a: Does the fact "at least one $x$ satisfies $P$" imply that "all $x$s satisfy $P$"?  I.e., does one black sheep imply all sheep are black?  ($x$ in this case is a formal variable of type "an element of some set", which set need not be $A$ or $Z$.  It's worthwhile to not make the error of thinking that the universe of all possible $X$s is restricted to just the elements of $A$ and $Z$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. Let's translate them to English.

---

**Claim (a):** If there is some real number $x$ that is both in $A$ and an integer, then every real number is both in $A$ and an integer.

This is certainly false, since the real number $x = 1$ is both in $A$ and an integer, yet there exists a real number (uncountably many actually) that is not in $A$ (also, there are uncountably many real numbers that aren't integers).

---

**Claim (b):** If every real number $x$ is both in $A$ and an integer, then there is some real number $x$ that is both in $A$ and an integer.

This is [vacuously true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), since the antecedent is false.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at $\alpha := (\exists x)P$ first. As $P(1)$ is true, since $1 \in A\land 1 \in \def\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z$, there is an $x$ such that $P$, hence $\alpha$ is true.

Now let's consider $\beta := (\forall x) P$. As $P(3)$ is false, since $3 \not\in A$, $P$ is not true for all $x$ (if the domain of the quantifiers is restricted to $A$, take $\pi$ as example). Hence $\beta$ is false.

(a) $\alpha \to \beta$ is false, as $\alpha$ is true, but $\beta$ isn't.

(b) $\beta \to \alpha$ is true, since $\beta$ is false (ex falso quodlibet)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{ 1,2,π \}$, and let $P$ be the statement "$x \in A \, \text {and} \, x \in \mathbb Z$".

Take the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers as the universal set, i.e.as *domain* of the interpretation.

Determine the truth value of each of the following implications :

> *(a)* $(∃x)P \Rightarrow (∀x)P$
>
> *(b)* $(∀x)P \Rightarrow (∃x)P$.

Try with *(a)*; it means, with the statemet $P$ of the example :

> $(∃x)(x \in A \land x \in \mathbb Z) \Rightarrow (∀x)(x \in A \land x \in \mathbb Z)$.

*Does it make sense now ?*

We have to "check" if it is *true* or *false* when the variable $x$ range over the domain of interpretation, which is the set $\mathbb R$ of *real* numbers.

First, the antecedent of the conditional : there is a number in $\mathbb R$ such that "$x \in A \, \text {and} \, x \in \mathbb Z$" is *true* for it ?

Sure : $1,2$ are both in $A$ and are *integers*; i.e. they belong to $\mathbb Z$.

Now, for the consequent of the conditional : is it true that for all *real* numbers "$x \in A \, \text {and} \, x \in \mathbb Z$" holds ?

Of course **no** : consider $3$; it obviously belongs to $\mathbb Z$ but it is not in $A$.

Thus, our conditional is $True \Rightarrow False$ which, by truth-functional properties of $\Rightarrow$ is $False$.

For *(b)*, the argument is similar...